# Opencv Sample code not working in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, opencv, release-mode

I downloaded opencv 2.4.5 and tried to configure in Visual studio 11. I tried compiling the below code in Debug mode by following the steps from this [link](http://www.anlak.com/using-opencv-2-3-1-with-visual-studio-2010-tutorial/). It works fine.

> But the same code get crahes in release mode.

The below is the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat img(Mat::zeros(100, 100, CV_8U));

    imshow("window", img);

    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my guess, there may be a linkage problem. For release mode you need to link with `release static libraries` For example, if a debug library is `opencv_imgproc243d.lib`, its release version is `opencv_imgproc243.lib`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the OpenCV .dll files in your executable folder.